# How to add bars between every few TableView cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to create a tableView that looks like this. (well, with different titles ;))

[image]

I saw those in a few apps so far and I cant figure out how to make those. Because of the tint (like in the navigation bar) and the similar appearance in various apps I guess that those are not custom cells but something different.

One more question (in case they are custom cells). When I change the cell heigh/background of a prototype cell in a storyboard tableview, it does not show in the app until I create an extra customcell class for it. What am i missing?

```
if (indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 7)
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TitleCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //heigh does not change -.-
    if (cell1 == nil){
        cell1 = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    return cell1;
}
else {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FirstCell";
UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell1 == nil){
    cell1 = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
cell1.textLabel.text = [[articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:labelkey1];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are section headers.

You can add section header by adding this method:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ 
     return @"My title";
}
```

For adding multiple sections you need to pass a suitable value from the following method:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 7;
}
```

Pass the number of rows in each section:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 2;
}
```

**From the above code you'll get 7 sections with 2 rows in each. You need to handle the sections, rows and their datas accordingly.**

> **tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:**
>
> Asks the data source for the title of the header of the specified
>   section of the table view.
>   - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section Parameters
>
> tableView
>
> ```
> The table-view object asking for the title.  section
>
> An index number identifying a section of tableView .
> ```
>
> Return Value
>
> A string to use as the title of the section header. If you return nil
>   , the section will have no title. Discussion
>
> The table view uses a fixed font style for section header titles. If
>   you want a different font style, return a custom view (for example, a
>   UILabel object) in the delegate method
>   tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: instead. Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> ```
>
> See Also
>
> ```
> – tableView:titleForFooterInSection:
> ```
>
> Declared In UITableView.h

Refer :

1. [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource)
2. [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)